# Angular 2 MVC debugging javascript

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to debug my main controller but in the dev tools it is not coming up, nor is my service..Is there a way i can debug my javascript files. I am not using type script..attached is my project structure I assume it has something to do with that..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the debugger of your browser you can just add the line "debugger;" to your code.

Usually it's just easier to use Chrome in Dev Tools mode (F12) then go to the sources tab and set breakpoints there.

Comment: I tried that...do you i have to include the js controller in my index.html page?

Comment: ya that would work to start but you probably want to avoid that type of setup in a prod environnement and use bundles. that's another topic.

Comment: @vidalsoon bundles don't exists in asp.net 5